# Eclipse plugin : How to sign plugin folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jarsigner, jar-signing

I'm using jarsigner to sign jar files successfully.
But there are some jars found as folder (extracted form).

Is there any command or option to pass this folder to the jarsigner and sign it?

Comment: If you are exporting a plugin there is a signing option on the export.

Comment: I need to do it automatically. outside eclipse.
using jarsigner command

Comment: I believe the maven Eclipse integration can do this